# Hide tab bar from View Controller in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have to create a simple label what uses auto layout and have a bottom space constrain. It should be 80 point far from the screen's bottom. The existing solution works until I don't connect the VC to a UITabBarController. In this case the tab bar appears on my VC's view and it changes the the values of my constraint> I'm hiding the tab bar programmatically and it works well when I run the app, the problem is my label detects the top of the tap bar as the bottom of the view, therefore it's on the wrong place after the view loaded. It's because the tab bar in IB, I'm almost sure. So the question is how can I hide the tab bar from a view controller (in IB) which root vc is a tab bar controller?

This is how it looks like in my Xcode: (I wanna hide the tab bar from the image)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the "Under bottom bars" box in the "Extend Edges" section?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did. I think it's the default value.